# jQuery paginator and :hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

This is my website: [Gutdesign](http://gutdesign.com.pl)

Click TV on the left side. You see now list of projects. Everything is good for me, but how to make this orange arrows hide at start? I want to show them when user move mouse on this area (`hover` effect). But how?

CSS "`display: none;`" and then on hover "`display: block;`" styles doesn't work :( Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `opacity: 0` to `.left_arrow` and `.right_arrow` and then create a new rule, `.left_arrow:hover` and `.right_arrow:hover`, and add `opacity: 1` to that rule.

```
// filter is used for IE8 and earlier 
.left_arrow, .right_arrow
{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}
.left_arrow:hover, .right_arrow:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with sprites. You make an image that has the arrow in the bottom and is blank in the top, and you use background-position to show the half that you want.

Example (I'm not seeing the page so the class names are only a reference):

```
.left_arrow a {background-image:url('../img/img.png')}
.left_arrow a {background-position:0px 0px}
.left_arrow a:hover {background-position:0px -72px}
```

More on sprites: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/26MVV/ (full jQuery) ?